# Can an Iranian with Italian residence enter Bulgaria visa free?

Tags: visas, bulgaria, iranian-citizens, italian-residents

I'm going to Bulgaria in a week. I'm an Iranian passport holder, with an Italian residence permit. I read that I don't need to apply for a visa because I have a Schengen residence permit. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is your Schengen visa that entitles you to enter Bulgaria, according the its [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html):

> **Visa-free regime for holders of Schengen visas for a stay of up to 90 days**
>
> On 25 January 2012 the Council of Ministers of the Republic of Bulgaria adopted a decision according to which by the date of Bulgaria’s accession to the Schengen area, our country will unilaterally apply a visa-free system for holders of valid Schengen visas. They will have the right to enter and reside in the Republic of Bulgaria for a period of no more than three months in any six-month period from the date of the first entry, without needing to have a Bulgarian short-stay visa. The decision entered into force on 31.01.2012.

Comment: The OP has a residence permit instead of a visa, though, and it looks like (somewhat strangely) residence permits are _not_ covered by Bulgaria's unilateral visa exemption. Note that the next section explicitly speaks about exemptions for holders of "valid visas _and residence permits_ issued by Romania, Cyprus and Croatia" so it's not as if the page you cite considers residence permits to be a form of visa.

Comment: (On the other hand, [here is a news item](http://www.novinite.com/articles/136079/Bulgaria+Opens+Doors+to+Schengen+Visa+Holders) that explicitly claims that the Bulgarian decision applies to Schengen residence permits too).

Comment: @HenningMakholm you can add it to my answer... I couldn't locate that. Doesn't the validity of an Italian resident permit coincide with a visa and OP didn't indicate permanent residency, as they're non-EU citizens and still use an Iranian passport.

Comment: x @Dorothy: No; a residence permit (whether permanent or time-limited) is an _alternative to_ a visa, not something one is generally supposed to hold _in addition to_ a visa. Se e,g. the [borders code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399), art. 6.1(b).

Comment: Our residence permit let us travel whitin Schengen area with no need for new visas, since Italy is in Schengen I assume it works for Bulgaria too! I hope so...